# bake all cloth sims at once

Tags: baking, cloth-simulation, cache

Is there a way to bake all cloth sims in the scene at once, or do I need to select every cloth object seperately? This would save me some time.

Comment: AFAIK there is no such option. But you could write a tiny python script for that.

Comment: Properties/physics/cloth/cache: "bake all dynamics".

Comment: thank you, this works